# think my Android app needs a pinch zoom and pan LAYOUT

Tags: android, layout, scroll, zooming, pinch

So. Iv'e got a straight forward relative layout which I add multiple ImageViews to.
I don't want the images to obscure each other so as they are added they are translated so they don't.
As more ImageViews are added they need to be translated further and further away from the centre of the layout so as not to overlap other images and so they fall off the edge of the user's screen - no problem so far ...
I need to give the user the ability to pan to see the images that are off screen and also zoom in and out (with gestures not buttons) to see all images or focus in on one.
I think the solution to this problem is to modify the layout to allow pinch and pan but all I can find is how to create views that support pinch and pan.
I need each image to be in a separate ImageView.
Forgive me if this is the wrong way to come at this problem but any help would be much appreciated.

This might help explain:

[want to scroll about and zoom around this layout (click to see)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LJ91.png)

Comment: @KrupalShah Please explain how that tutorial will answer the question.

Comment: I know how to pinch and pan an ImageView I would like to pinch and pan a Layout with multiple ImageViews in it. I want the user to scroll and zoom around the whole view even tho it is larger than the screen.

Comment: In other words ... When an ImageView is translated outside of the boundaries of the visible screen (the Layout) how would one go about allowing the user to pan to see it or zoom out to see it?

Comment: this might help explain what i mean. sorry for my awefuly phraased question       http://i.stack.imgur.com/4LJ91.png

Comment: see http://pastebin.com/Sh0XpA91, get the detectors from [here](https://github.com/pskink/android-gesture-detectors)

Comment: and you can do exactly the same with any layout class - it doesn't have to be a custom view

Comment: looks promising - i needed to make myself a 'shove' gesture handler too so double good!

Comment: will let you know how things turn out. Cheers Buddy!

Comment: Late answer but I think you can use this library https://github.com/natario1/ZoomLayout